# Pointwise limit of bounded operators is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Theorem**: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a normed vector space. Let $(T_n)\in B(X,Y)$ be a sequence of bounded operaotrs from $X$ to $Y$. If $(T_nx)$ converges for every $x\in X$, then the operator
> $$
> T:X\to Y,
> $$
> where $Tx=\lim T_nx$ is linear and bounded.

It's clear to me that $T$ is linear. However, the proof that it is bounded says something that I'm not sure why is true. It's the following:

> **What I don't understand**: For each $x\in X$ we have that $\sup_n||T_nx||<\infty$. Why is this true?

Answer (score 2):

$T_nx$ is a convergent sequence. Convergent sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A converging sequence is bounded. Hence, it follows immediately.

Comment: You probably don't mean to include "the supremum of" in the first sentence? The supremum where it exists is a single number and thus bounded, but one uses boundedness of the sequence $\|T_nx\|$ to see that it exists.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks for pointing out.